# using self executing function in javascript properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to use the self-executing function with rails 6 but I have an error. I cannot figure out what is the issue

here is the code

../javascript/pack/show.js

```
var Show = (function(){
    var init = function(){
        alert("hello world!");
    };
    return{
        init: init
    };
})();
```

and this is the erb file

```
  .....
   <%=javascript_pack_tag 'show' %>

   <script>
    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
      Show.init();
})

</script>
```

in the console it says

**ReferenceError: Show is not defined**  when view the page

i cannot find the issue

Comment: try `window.Show` ?

Comment: window.Show did not solved it . window, Show is undefined